# Does "across from" mean necessarily facing each other?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

My textbook says that the post office and the hospital are next to each other. Shouldn't they be across from each other since there's a street between them?

Does across from mean they have to be facing each other?

[image]

Comment: That thing between them might just be an alley, not a major street, and since they're facing the same major street, it still seems more correct to say they're next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a small street between the two buildings. I could see someone saying that the post office is across the street from the hospital. From our current vantage point it would be weird to say that however. I'd say that they are next to each other if we were speaking from this point of view.